# Liquid translate array

Tags: jekyll, translation, liquid

I'm trying to translate movie directors array in liquid

Source data:

movies.yaml

```
- name: Titatic
  director: James Cameron
- name: Avatar
  director: James Cameron
- name: A Beautiful Mind
  director: Ron Howard
```

cast.yaml

```
"James Cameron": "Джеймс Кэмерон"
"Ron Howard": "Рон Ховард"
```

movie.html (portion for simplicity)

```
{% if page.lang == "ru" %}
  {% for director in movie.Director %}
     {% assign directors = directors | concat: site.data.cast[director] %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
     {% directors = movie.Director %}
{% endif %}
{{ directors | join: ", " }
```

But can't concat array with the translated director name due to error:

> concat filter requires an array argument included

Any suggestions?

Comment: "But can't" is not a problem description. What happens? Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up to this

```
{% assign directors = movie.Director | join: ", " %}
{% if page.lang == "ru" %}
  {% for director in movie.Director %}
    {% assign directors = directors | replace: director, site.data.cast[director] %}
  {% endfor %}                          
{% endif %}
{{ directors }}
```